# Is there an item that prevents expending a power on a miss?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, powers

I know that some powers have the Reliable Keyword. Is there an item that prevents me from expending a power on a miss? I've read my share of books, but it is just too many books.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Not really, they would be much too powerful.**

There are some limited items however, like the Pearl of Power from the Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium:

> Trigger: You miss all targets with an encounter attack power of level 3 or lower.
>   Effect: You do not expend the use of the power.

But this is a daily power of a 7th level item.

**What you *can* buy is more accuracy, which is actually better.**
Even if you do not expend the power, you wasted your action. Still having that daily after 3 rounds of consecutive missing is not that great. Definitely not worth any investment.

- Eagle Eye Goggles gives you a bonus to Ranged Basic Attacks
- Laurel Circlet gives you a bonus to Illusion attacks
- Headband of Intellect gives you a bonus to Psychic attacks. Even better with a Githyanki Silver Weapon, as it can make all your attacks psychic
- An Accurate implement, together with the Superior Implement Trainig feat gives you a bonus to every implement attack
- Frost Weapon with the feats Wintertouched and Lasting Frost gives you almost permanent Combat Advantage, and a damage bonus as well