# Adding the Reliable Keyword

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

I realize that daily powers are either Reliable, or they do something even if you miss. But is there any way to *add* the Reliable keyword to a power?

It's possible with certain other keywords; for example, Hounding Assault<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10740)</sup> adds Rattling to all of your melee attacks for the remainder of the encounter... but is there any way to do it with a keyword as powerful as Reliable? Even if it can only be done once per day, or if it requires party cooperation (such as making an *ally's* power Reliable), can it be done at all?

This question came up while bemoaning the errata to Hobble<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10759)</sup>, which removed the Reliable keyword. Ideally, I'd like to see an answer that provides a means to make Hobble Reliable once again (post-errata), but if there is a means to grant Reliable that doesn't work on Hobble, that's fine.

Comment: Are you actually after how to add the Reliable keyword, or do you just want to not expend powers on a miss? The latter would necessarily _include_ any solutions involving the Reliable keyword, whilst not presupposing that's the _only_ kind of solution. (If you edit your question to just be about not expending powers, it could also serve as our canonical question for this whole topic, it looks like. Note that the other question is limited to items, so doesn't cover feats, other powers, class features, etc.)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs, The idea prompting the question was abusing a "Reliable" Hobble by MC into Rogue with 8-10 Dex and a nonmagical weapon to use Hobble with, all but ensuring that a critical hit is required to expend the power but still getting the Effect line of Hobble. A controller running around with autohit "knock prone, can't stand up (save ends)" for a full encounter would be strong if it were still possible. If there were a means to not expend a specific power on a miss for a full encounter, that's mechanically identical to giving the power Reliable. Simply recharging the power once is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can not give the Reliable keyword to a power, but it is possible to regain it in other ways.**

One of the most useful possibilities is the Warlord's No Gambit is Wasted, and there are other similar powers and items.

[But you know what is even better than regaining a power after a miss? Hitting on the first attempt.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36492/is-there-an-item-that-prevents-expending-a-power-on-a-miss/36495#36495)

Comment: While hitting on the first try is normally superior to getting the chance to try again (and I normally try to make my characters as accurate as possible), the idea here is to abuse the combination of Reliable, low chance to hit, and a power's Effect line to get the Effect over and over again. (Specifically Hobble, but I'm sure there are other powers which could be similarly abused if this were possible.)

Comment: Hobble's effect is not so great, and definitely not worth a Standard action. But you are right, sometimes the Miss or Effect lines are better than the Hit. My favorite is Lead by Example.